# Selenium Help-To pass value in by.cssSelector

Tags: selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I am trying to import data driven framework in the selenium webdriver.

```
 string passValue;
 passValue = xlData[row][col];
 for (int row = 1; row < xlData.length; row++) {
     for(int col = 0; col < xlData[0].length; col++) {
        wt.until(ExpectedConditions.elementsTobeclickable(By.cssSelectors("option[value=passValue]"))).click();

   //How To pass value in above line of code?

    }
}
  //same question for the xpath as well
```

Comment: it's extremely difficult trying to figure out what you are asking for.  Could you reiterate what in particular you are trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

is this what you mean:

Take the variable and insert it into the css? or xpath? etc

```
wt.until(ExpectedConditions.elementsTobeclickable(By.cssSelectors("option[value=" + passValue + "]"))).click();
```